# Displaying different app name in App Store and on home screen

Tags: ios, ios5

Apparently some apps display a different name on the app store details page than they do once downloaded and placed on the home screen.

This makes good sense since space is highly limited underneath the app icon on the home screen. My question is how to do this?

Where is the name used on the home screen defined?

Where is the name used on the app store applications detail page defined?

Regards

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The name used  on the app store applications page detail is defined on iTunes Connect when you upload the app.

The name of your binary is in your Project Setting underneath the Info panel (Bundle display name) when you select your target.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Can you update the "Bundle display name" if you upload an updated app later on?

Comment: Yes, I never done it but it seemed easy. Be careful, the name of your app in iTunes connect can NOT be changed. But the executable name that will be displayed in home screen yes : http://techtips.salon.com/change-iphone-app-name-3644.html

Comment: Thank you for verifying this :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work any more. Regardless of what I name my CFBundleDisplayName, my app seems to match the name in App Store Connect. I wonder if they changed this?

Answer (score 21):

Just to elaborate on @Ganzolo's answer, these images show where each of those are defined. The home screen title is defined in your app's info.plist file in the bundle display name string, and the App Store page name is set when you click add new app in iTunes Connect

[image: Under App title]

[image: iTunes Connect add new app page]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, it's appreciated