# App descriptive caption

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I could not find any data on the documentation ,or on the net, about the descriptive caption of an app in the store .

I know i can add more words to the app name to describe it , but i don't understand, does Apple show on the device ONLY the first words before the `:` ? 
i don't want to get the  `....` after the app name on the device  because the name is too long..

I am trying to understand, if the words before `:` or `-` , is taken out on the device ,without getting the "`...`"

Thanks .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying different app name in App Store and on home screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483532/displaying-different-app-name-in-app-store-and-on-home-screen)

Answer (score 0):

The descriptive caption and the app name shown in the device are different, and they are introduced in different places.
The app name is introduced in the Xcode project. You can see whether the complete app name will be shown by compiling your project and running it either in the simulator or device. If the `...` appear, then you need to shorten the device app name.
The app descriptive caption, as you name it, is introduced in iTunes Connect and *may be* totally different from the device app name. It is only shown in iTunes and doesn't have anything to do with the app name shown in the device.
Sorry for the repetitive way of this response, but I have made all efforts so it is absolutely clear.
Finally, as an example, imagine your app name is *The Best App in the World*. So that is the name your app has, but it doesn't fit in the device! So the name you gave it in your Xcode project could perfectly be *TBAITW*, or *BestApp*, etc.

Comment: thanks, but i am not sure about something you said. when you create an app name on the iTunes, you first check if its already  taken ,so, what you said is not entirely true because i can't just choose a name on iTunes than put completely other name on device (Xcode). i think the " ; " has to do with it, so words after the ";" , are not counted or something .

Comment: The question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483532/displaying-different-app-name-in-app-store-and-on-home-screen